# Datagrid Columns Not Fitting Print Preview Page

Tags: vb.net

i've been trying to print some records with more than 7 columns it is shown on the datagrid.but the columns are not fitting the page below are the screenshots

[image]

Below is how the datagridview to be printed looks like
[image]

Below is the code i used for the printdocument tool

```
  Dim mRow As Integer = 0

    Dim newpage As Boolean = True

    Private Sub PrintDocument1_PrintPage(sender As Object, e As Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage
        ' sets it to show '...' for long text
        Dim fmt As StringFormat = New StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.LineLimit)
        fmt.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center
        fmt.Trimming = StringTrimming.EllipsisCharacter
        Dim y As Int32 = e.MarginBounds.Top
        Dim rc As Rectangle
        Dim x As Int32
        Dim h As Int32 = 0
        Dim row As DataGridViewRow

        ' print the header text for a new page
        '   use a grey bg just like the control
        If newpage Then
            row = datagrid1.Rows(mRow)
            x = e.MarginBounds.Left
            For Each cell As DataGridViewCell In row.Cells
                ' since we are printing the control's view,
                ' skip invidible columns
                If cell.Visible Then
                    rc = New Rectangle(x, y, cell.Size.Width, cell.Size.Height)

                    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.LightGray, rc)
                    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, rc)

                    ' reused in the data pront - should be a function
                    Select Case datagrid1.Columns(cell.ColumnIndex).DefaultCellStyle.Alignment
                        Case DataGridViewContentAlignment.BottomRight,
                             DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight
                            fmt.Alignment = StringAlignment.Far
                            rc.Offset(-1, 0)
                        Case DataGridViewContentAlignment.BottomCenter,
                            DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
                            fmt.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center
                        Case Else
                            fmt.Alignment = StringAlignment.Near
                            rc.Offset(2, 0)
                    End Select

                    e.Graphics.DrawString(datagrid1.Columns(cell.ColumnIndex).HeaderText, datagrid1.Font, Brushes.Black, rc, fmt)
                    x += rc.Width
                    h = Math.Max(h, rc.Height)
                End If
            Next
            y += h

        End If
        newpage = False

        ' now print the data for each row
        Dim thisNDX As Int32
        For thisNDX = mRow To datagrid1.RowCount - 1
            ' no need to try to print the new row
            If datagrid1.Rows(thisNDX).IsNewRow Then Exit For

            row = datagrid1.Rows(thisNDX)
            x = e.MarginBounds.Left
            h = 0

            ' reset X for data
            x = e.MarginBounds.Left

            ' print the data
            For Each cell As DataGridViewCell In row.Cells
                If cell.Visible Then
                    rc = New Rectangle(x, y, cell.Size.Width, cell.Size.Height)

                    ' SAMPLE CODE: How To 
                    ' up a RowPrePaint rule
                    'If Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells(5).Value) < 9.99 Then
                    '    Using br As New SolidBrush(Color.MistyRose)
                    '        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(br, rc)
                    '    End Using
                    'End If

                    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, rc)

                    Select Case datagrid1.Columns(cell.ColumnIndex).DefaultCellStyle.Alignment
                        Case DataGridViewContentAlignment.BottomRight,
                             DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight
                            fmt.Alignment = StringAlignment.Far
                            rc.Offset(-1, 0)
                        Case DataGridViewContentAlignment.BottomCenter,
                            DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
                            fmt.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center
                        Case Else
                            fmt.Alignment = StringAlignment.Near
                            rc.Offset(2, 0)
                    End Select

                    e.Graphics.DrawString(cell.FormattedValue.ToString(),
                                          datagrid1.Font, Brushes.Black, rc, fmt)

                    x += rc.Width
                    h = Math.Max(h, rc.Height)
                End If

            Next
            y += h
            ' next row to print
            mRow = thisNDX + 1

            If y + h > e.MarginBounds.Bottom Then
                e.HasMorePages = True
                ' mRow -= 1   causes last row to rePrint on next page
                newpage = True
                Return
            End If
        Next


    End Sub
```

this is the code for the print button

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        PrintPreviewDialog1.Document = PrintDocument1
        PrintPreviewDialog1.ShowDialog()
    End Sub
```

Comment: You may need to decrease the margins `.DefaultPageSettings.Margins = New Printing.Margins(25, 25, 25, 25)`

Comment: Looks like this needs to be Landscape not Portrait.